# XCode: "None of your accounts are member..." of a Team-ID coming from shared Libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

## TL;DR:

XCode complains that we are not member of a specific Team-ID that is only used in 2 third-party-libraries.

## The Issue:

Over many months i could create an archive for Testflight with our app. Suddenly it isn't possible anymore. It gives the error shown in the screenshot: "None of your accounts are Member of Team ID '5WFBC66J2G'".

The interesting part is, that our Team-ID is different than this one stated in the error message. So I did a grep for this Team-ID and encountered that it is used only in RSKImageCropper and QBImagePicker.

Without these libraries our app can be shipped and pushed to AppStore/TestFlight. But with these libraries included we stumble upon the TeamID coming from XCode-Projects that are owned by third party libraries.

I restartet Xcode, i re-created the app from scratch with all required files. It still gives this error. How can i narrow it?

## This is our Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'XXXXXX' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for XXXXX
  
  pod 'RSKImageCropper' 
  pod 'QBImagePickerController'

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
    'ART',
  ]

end
```

[image: Error]

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen with automatic signing? Are you logged into your account in Xcode Preferences?

Comment: i am logged in and can build several apps but not this one anymore

Comment: Just updated the question due to new information

Answer (score 1):

- Log in to github under your account,
- create a fork of libraries you need,
- clone them to your local computer,
- configure in them no provisioning,
- and commit to your github.

Then use them as pods instead of the regular ones, in the following way:

```
pod 'RSKImageCropper', :git => 'https://github.com/<your github username>/RSKImageCropper.git', :commit => '<sha-of-your-commit>',

...
```